# How to print path of a file properly?

Tags: c, linux, shell, pwd

Trying to make a pwd for the c shell. This is what I found on a website and wanted to learn more about it.
I have use debugging printf statements all the way through the program already and it returns the "." instead of the actual dir name all the way through. What am I missing? Why would this be happening?

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    struct stat stat_buf;   
    struct dirent *file_info;
    ino_t itself_ino;       /* holds current folder inode */
    ino_t parent_ino;       /* holds parent folder inode */
    char Current[PATH_MAX];  /* folder name */
    char Path[PATH_MAX];     /* holds the full path */
    char Slash[PATH_MAX];    /* add / before the folder name */ 
    DIR *dir;

    while (1)
    {   
        dir = opendir(".");
        if(dir == NULL) { 
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot get current directory.\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        /* read the information about the current folder */
        file_info = readdir(dir);

        lstat(file_info->d_name, &stat_buf);
        itself_ino = stat_buf.st_ino;
        closedir(dir);

        chdir("..");    /* go to parent directory */
        dir = opendir(".");

        file_info = readdir(dir);
        lstat(file_info->d_name, &stat_buf);
        parent_ino = stat_buf.st_ino;

        if(itself_ino == parent_ino) {
            /*closedir(dir);*/
            break;
        } else {
            strcpy(Slash, "/");
            strcpy(Current, file_info->d_name);
            strcat(Slash, Current);  /* add "/" as the first */ 
            strcat(Slash, Path);     /* charcter of the directory */ 

            /* check the length of the pathname */
            if(strlen(Slash)  >= PATH_MAX) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Path too long!\n");
                exit(0);
            }           
            /* save the full pathname */       
            strcpy(Path, Slash);
        }
        closedir(dir);
    }

    /* print the full path of the current working directory */
    printf("%s\n", Path);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

It's just [realpath](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html):

```
if (realpath(".", &Path) == NULL) {
   // handle error
}
```

However maybe you aim at `getcwd` or `get_current_dir_name`.

```
printf("%s\n", get_current_dir_name());
```